# Graph API get source device of posts

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am using facebook graph API to search public informations, So how could i get information are those infos uploaded from pc, android, iphone or from some other platform.

Here is example of my [search url](https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=mark)

Comment: Did you parse the results? There is an _"application"_ tag with _"id"_ and _"name"_ tags within. That is closest you can come to finding what created the story / post / feed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So how could i get information are those infos uploaded from pc, android, iphone or from some other platform.

Not at all.

You could at most get a list of devices a user has used to access Facebook – see the `devices` field of the [user](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) object. That gives you the info, if they use/have used an iOS or Android device at some point.

But this info is not available for individual posts/photos etc.

The [post](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) object has a field `application`, though – that *might* give you a hint, if the user used some special application to post the message, one that’s only targetet at a special kind of device maybe.